# Warning: 'Invalid .internal.selfref detected' when adding a column to a data.table returned from a function

Tags: r, data.table

This seems as `fread` bug, but I am not sure.

This example reproduce my problem. I have a function where I read a data.table and return it in a list. i use list to group other results in the same structure. Here my code:

```
ff.fread <- function(){
  dt = fread("x
1
2
")
  list(dt=dt)   
}

DT.f <- ff.fread()$dt
```

Now when I try to add a new column to DT.f, it works but I get a warning message:

```
DT.f[,y:=1:2]
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(DT.f, , `:=`(y, 1:2)) :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a copy of the whole
  table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point,
  this data.table has been copied by R (or been created manually using
  structure() or similar). Avoid key<-, names<- and attr<- which in R currently
  (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid
  copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. Also, in R<v3.1.0, list(DT1,DT2) copied
  the entire DT1 and DT2 (R's list() used to copy named objects); please upgrade
  to R>=v3.1.0 if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please report to
  datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.
```

Note the if I create the data.table manually I don't have this warning. This works fine for example:

```
ff <- function(){
      list(dt=data.table(x=1:2))
    }
DT <- ff()$dt
DT[,y:=1:2]
```

Or if I don't return the result of `fread` within a list , it works also fine

```
ff.fread <- function(){
  dt = fread("x
1
2
")
  dt
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with `fread` and everything to do with `list`, here's a simpler example: `dt = data.table(a = 1); l = list(dt); dt1 = l[[1]]; dt1[, b := 2]`

Comment: Note that the warning message did say that `list()` copies named inputs. Full warning message now edited in.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `fread` per se, but that you're calling `list()` and passing it a named object. We can recreate this by doing:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=1:2)       # name the object 'DT'
DT.l <- list(DT=DT)           # create a list containing one data.table
y <- DT.l$DT                  # get back the data.table
y[, bla := 1L]                # now add by reference
# works fine but warning message will occur

DT.l = list(DT=data.table(x=1:2))   # DT = a call, not a named object
y = DT.l$DT
y[, bla:=1L]
# works fine and no warning message
```

#### Good news:

The good news is that from R version >= 3.1.0 (now in devel), passing a named object to `list()` will **no longer** create a copy, rather, its reference count (number of objects pointing to this value) just gets bumped. So, the problem goes away with the next version of R.

To understand how `data.table` detects copies using `.internal.selfref`, we'll dive into some history of `data.table`.

#### First, some history:

You should know that `data.table` over-allocates column pointer slots (truelength is set to a default of 100) on creation so that `:=` can be used to add columns by reference later on. There was one issue with this as such - handling copies. For example, when we call `list()` and pass it a named object, a copy is being made, as illustrated below.

```
tracemem(DT)
# [1] "<0x7fe23ac3e6d0>"
DT.list <- list(DT=DT)    # `DT` is the named object on the RHS of = here
# tracemem[0x7fe23ac3e6d0 -> 0x7fe23cd72f48]:
```

The problem with any copy of `data.table` that R makes (not `data.table`'s `copy()`) is that R internally sets the `truelength` parameter to 0  even though `truelength(.)` function will still return the correct result. This inadvertently led to a *segfault* when updated by reference with `:=`, because, the *over-allocation* didn't exist anymore (or at least is not recognised anymore). This happened in versions < 1.7.8. In order to overcome this, an attribute called `.internal.selfref` was introduced. You can check this attribute by doing `attributes(DT)`.

From NEWS (of v1.7.8):

> o The 'Chris crash' is fixed. The root cause was that `key<-` always copies the whole table. *The problem with that copy (other than being slower) is that R doesn't maintain the over allocated `truelength`, but it looks as though it has*. `key<-` was used internally, in particular in `merge()`. So, adding a column using `:=` after `merge()` was a memory overwrite, since the over allocated memory wasn't really there after `key<-`'s copy.
>
> `data.tables` now have a new attribute `.internal.selfref` to catch and warn about such copies in future. All internal use of `key<-` has been replaced with `setkey()`, or new function `setkeyv()` which accepts a vector, and do not copy.

#### What does this `.internal.selfref` do?

It just points to itself, basically. It's simply an attribute attached to `DT` that contains the address in RAM of `DT`. If R inadvertently copies `DT`, the address of `DT` will move in RAM but the attribute attached will still contain the old memory address, they won't match any more. `data.table` checks they do match (i.e. is valid) before adding a new column by reference into a spare column pointer slot.

#### How is `.internal.selfref` implemented ?

In order to understand this attribute `.internal.selfref`, we've to understand what an *external pointer* (`EXTPTRSXP`) is. [This page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_122.html) explains nicely. Copy/pasting the essential lines:

> External pointer SEXPs are intended to handle references to C structures such as *handles*, and are used for this purpose in package RODBC for example. They are unusual in their copying semantics in that when an R object is copied, the external pointer object is not duplicated.

They are created as:

```
SEXP R_MakeExternalPtr(void *p, SEXP tag, SEXP prot);
```

> where p is the pointer (and hence this cannot portably be a function pointer), and tag and prot are references to ordinary R objects which will remain in existence (be protected from garbage collection) for the lifetime of the external pointer object. A useful convention is to use the tag field for some form of type identification and the prot field for protecting the memory that the external pointer represents, if that memory is allocated from the R heap.

In our case, we create the attribute `.internal.selfref` of/for DT, whose value is an external pointer to NULL (the address of which you see in the attribute value) and this external pointer's `prot` field is another external pointer back to `DT` (hence referred to as *selfref*) with its `prot` set to NULL this time.

**Note:** We've to employ this extptr to NULL whose 'prot' is an extptr strategy so that `identical(DT1, DT2)` which are two different copies, but with same content returns TRUE. (If you don't understand what this means, you can just skip to the next part. It's not relevant to understanding the answer to this question).

#### Okay, how does this all work then?

We know that the external pointer **does not** get duplicated during a copy. Basically, when we create a data.table, the attribute .internal.selfref creates an external pointer to NULL with it's `prot` field creating an external pointer back to `DT`. Now, when an unintentional "copy" is being made, the object's address gets modified but not the address protected by the attribute. It still points to `DT` whether it exists or not.. because it won't/can't be modified. This is therefore detected internally by checking the address of the current object and the address protected by the external pointer. If they don't match, then a "copy" has been made by R (that would have lost the over-allocation that data.table carefully created). That is:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:2) # internal selfref set
DT.list <- list(DT=DT)  # copy made, address(DT.list$DT) != address(DT)
                        # and truelength would be affected.

DT.new <- DT.list$DT    # address of DT.new != address of DT
                        # and it's not equal to the address pointed to by
                        # the attribute's 'prot' external pointer

# so a re-over-allocation has to be made by data.table at the next update by
# reference, and it warns so you can fix the root cause by not using list(),
# key<-, names<- etc.
```

That's a lot to take in. I think I've managed to get it through as clear as possible. If there're any mistakes (it took me a while to wrap this around my head) or possibilities for further clarity, feel free to edit or comment with your suggestions.

Hope this clears up things.

Comment: The warining message contain this : ` Also, in R<v3.1.0, list(DT1,DT2) copied the entire DT1 and DT2`, If i understand , the problem is from the R list that copy named objects, Where not just to put list(DT1) ( a single table not 2 tables)?

Comment: You're right. I've removed the ref. to `tag` altogether (although it plays a small part). I think this is sufficient to get the idea though.

Comment: I think the warning refers to a frequent case. But as long as a copy happens (that's not through the actual `copy` function), or anyhow unintentional, then, `:=` has to be copied properly in order to update by reference (because it's truelength would be set to 0)...

Comment: last thing , in your example , if I remove the attribute `setattr(y,'.internal.selfref',NULL)` , I still get the warning. I imagine that the attribute is not really dropped just hidden..

Comment: Yes, the attribute set to NULL is also checked. Basically, once a DT is created, it's internal.ref (prot's extptr) has to be there and it has to point back to DT's address. Else you'll have a warning + copy.

Comment: Arun thank a lot for this great answer!+10 if I can!

Comment: #Arun thanks for this explanation, very helpful!  When you get a chance, please update the stale weblink to "This page", I'd suggest to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#External-pointers-and-weak-references (which I found after looking up https://web.archive.org/web/20190301004708/http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_122.html ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Arun's answer is a great explanation.  The specific feature of `list()` in R <= 3.0.2 is that it copies *named inputs* (things that have been named before the call to `list()`). In r-devel now (the next version of R), this copy by `list()` no longer happens and all will be well. It's a very welcome change in R.

In the meantime, you can work around it by creating the output list in a different way.

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"
```

First demonstrate list() copying :

```
> DT = data.table(a=1:3)
> address(DT)
[1] "0x1d70010"
> address(list(DT)[[1]])
[1] "0x21bc178"    # different address => list() copied the data.table named DT
> data.table:::selfrefok(DT)
[1] 1
> data.table:::selfrefok(list(DT)[[1]])
[1] 0              # i.e. this copied DT is not over-allocated
```

Now a different way to create the same list :

```
> ans = list()
> ans$DT = DT    # use $<- instead
> address(DT)
[1] "0x1d70010"
> address(ans$DT)
[1] "0x1d70010"    # good, no copy
> identical(ans, list(DT=DT))
[1] TRUE
> data.table:::selfrefok(ans$DT)
[1] 1              # good, the list()-ed DT is still over-allocated ok
```

Convoluted and confusing, I know.  Using `$<-` to create the output list, or even just placing the call to `fread` inside the call to `list()` i.e. `list(DT=fread(...))` should avoid the copy by `list()`.